# Errors 2502 & 2503 When Installing MSIs

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to install a number of items that are MSI files from Microsoft suchs as SQLTypeCLRs.msi and SharedComponents.msi for SQL Server. When I try and install these I get errors 2502 & 2503 and it fails with a call runtime error. If I open a Command Prompt in Administrator mode and then start the MSI from that command line then it will run as adminsitrator. It's almost as though it doesn't try to access UAC. And you can't right click and click "Run As Administrator" on the file. Is there a way to fix this so it runs MSIs as Administrator so I don't keep getting these errors? I am getting this on my 2 Windows Server 2016 boxes.

I am simply tryihg to install new software that comes to me as MSIs and not EXEs.

Error 2503.Called RunScript when not marked in progress.

Error 2502.Called InstallFinalize when no install in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your MSI does not have the Word Count Summary property set correctly. It must be set to 3 to ask for UAC's elevation. (info [there](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/word-count-summary))

> Bit 3     0 8     Elevated privileges can be required to install this
>   package. Elevated privileges are not required to install this package.
>   Available starting with Windows Installer version 4.0 and Windows
>   Vista or Windows Server 2008.

With [MSIInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/msiinfo-exe) (with -w flag), a tool from the Windows SDK, we can read the msi information to see if it's the case, it can modify it too I think. I'am not familar with the use of the tool.

ORCA's tool can be used to set the bit correctly too.

As seen from that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080131/how-to-make-a-setup-work-for-limited-non-admin-users), and quoted only the important details;

> ..
>   Step 5 - Flip bit 3 of the word count property in the summary information stream to signal no credential prompt is required. 
>   
> ..
>   NOTE: Step 5 can be done using Orca, Microsoft's MSI editing tool.
>   Open the MSI file in Orca, select View-->Summary Information... then
>   check the "UAC Compliant" checkbox.
>
> NOTE #4: Yet another way to do Step 5, use the MsiInfo.exe tool
>   included in the "Windows SDK Components for Windows Installer
>   Developers"
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370310(VS.85).aspx

Comment: These MSIs are made by Symantec and Microsoft so I think they have them set correctly. They should be pushing for UAC on launch.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to the ShellExecuteEx issue which fixed this issues as well.

[Domain Admins UAC Permission On Domain Controller](https://serverfault.com/questions/988422/domain-admins-uac-permission-on-domain-controller/988429#988429)